# Using GGTS on Windows, can I setup the middle click button to copy and paste like that in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, grails, groovy, ggts

When I run Eclipse on Linux (Ubuntu), I can quickly copy and paste code using the middle click button on my mouse. Is there a way to set this up on Windows for Groovy/Grails Tool Suite (GGTS)? Thanks

Edit: If it matters any, I am running Version 3.6.0 RELEASE on Eclipse Luna 4.4

Comment: This functionality is actually handled by your window manager in *nix. There are addons for windows to expand the copy/paste capabilities of the clipboard such as AutoClipX. Here is some other possible solutions as well: http://superuser.com/questions/84550/select-to-copy-and-middle-click-to-paste-in-windows